# Equivalence of Rathjen's continuum hypothesis and another form of the CH without choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, continuum-hypothesis

(This question is [already posted on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2321286/53976) but it isn't answered, so I ask same question on this site.)

The following form of a continuum hypothesis occurs in Rathjen's paper "Indefiniteness in semi-intuitionistic set theories: On a conjecture of Feferman":

> Every non-empty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a surjective image of $\omega$ or $\mathbb{R}$ is a surjective image of $A$. That is, $$\forall A\subseteq \mathbb{R} \exists f : (A\neq\varnothing \to f : \omega \twoheadrightarrow A \>\vee\> f: A\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}).$$

ZFC can prove the Rathjen's continuum hypothesis is equivalent in following form of a continuum hypothesis:

> There is no set $A$ such that $\aleph_0<|A|<2^{\aleph_0}$

but it doesn't seem obvious it is equivalent in ZF. I believe they are not equivalent but I can't prove this. Thanks in advance.

(As a consequence, I have a doubt that we can definitely say Rathjen's paper shows SCS can't prove $\mathsf{CH\lor\lnot CH}$, but I don't want to go further before knowing whether two forms of the continuum hypothesis are equivalent in ZF.)

---

Asaf notices the second form of the CH implies Rathjen's one. Here is a proof in ZF:
Assume that $A$ is an infinite set of reals. [An argument by Noah](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321286/two-forms-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-are-they-equivalent-in-zf#comment4778002_2321286) shows $A$ can't be Dedekind-finite. Therefore by assumption, there are two possibilities: either $|A|= \aleph_0$ or $|A|= 2^{\aleph_0}$.